# Как выпускать луч из локальный координат в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, как выпускать рейкаст из локального направления? То есть в направлении, куда направлена ось Z (синяя).
Я думаю, что его еще нужно правильно отрисовать в гизмосе.

[image: gif]

Вот мой код сейчас:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(rayPoint.position, Vector3.forward);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out _hit, _rayDistance, _raycastLayers))
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, _hit.point, Color.red);
    }
```

Comment: Код здесь надо вставлять текстом

Answer (score 0):

Нужно преобразовать направление луча из глобального в локальное, путём использования transform.TransformDirection() или просто transform.forward

```
Ray ray = new Ray(rayPoint.position, transform.forward);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out _hit, _rayDistance, _raycastLayers))
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, _hit.point, Color.red);
    }
```